# Wordpress: How to insert a dropdown menu to WP theme?

Tags: wordpress, drop-down-menu, menu, themes

Can't seem to find a solution to this one on the web. I'm completely clueless to the intertwining mechanisms of Java, CSS and PHP.

My WP theme does not support a drop down menu - I'd like to know how to insert one manually. A basic one normally seen would be good enough for me.

(www.cakwa.com)

```
.nav { 

}
.nav ul { 
    list-style: none;   
    font-size: 1.1em; 
    text-transform: uppercase; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    margin: 0 -20px 0px 0; 
    float: right; 
}
.nav ul li { 
    float: left; 
    margin: 0 20px 0 18px; 
}
.nav ul li a{ 
    color: #A6A8AC;    
}
.nav ul li a:hover, .nav ul li.active a{ 
    color: #535659;    
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Every theme have drop down menu function. And rustik have too. Just go to Appearance>Menu 
Then add your menus. Just slide the menu option to the right hand side to change them as a dropdown